# Is there a way to fix GDB 9.2's problem with function preamble or to disable its generation in GCC 9.3?

Tags: gcc, gdb

Since upgrading to GCC 9.3 and GDB 9.2 (chosen by APT):

The general preample problem is that the arguments don't become available at the beginning of the function but on the first statement:

```
Thread 3 "lexe.inc.exe" hit Breakpoint 1, bitGenNode (T=0x0, Gen=0x0, Node=0x0) at ../bitGen/bitGen.c:433
433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
(gdb) p Node
$2 = (bitNode *) 0x0
(gdb) n
434     mySubProc(T, Gen, Node);
(gdb) p Node
$3 = (bitNode *) 0x7ffff5958d50
```

In general the arguments aren't even 0 (they can be any stack-garbage, even something that looks valid). This is bad and confusing enough, but it gets worse, see below.

But first for those who have not seen this: there are these e.g. 7 instructions before the first statement and they make the arguments available.

```
Thread 3 "lexe.inc.exe" hit Breakpoint 1, bitGenNode (T=0x0, Gen=0x0, Node=0x0) at ../bitGen/bitGen.c:433
433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
(gdb) display/i $pc
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dedf3 <bitGenNode>: endbr64 
(gdb) ni
0x00007ffff79dedf7  433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dedf7 <bitGenNode+4>:   push   %rbp
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff79dedf8  433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dedf8 <bitGenNode+5>:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff79dedfb  433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dedfb <bitGenNode+8>:   sub    $0x50,%rsp
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff79dedff  433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dedff <bitGenNode+12>:  mov    %rdi,-0x38(%rbp)
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff79dee03  433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dee03 <bitGenNode+16>:  mov    %rsi,-0x40(%rbp)
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff79dee07  433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff79dee07 <bitGenNode+20>:  mov    %rdx,-0x48(%rbp)
(gdb) 
434     mySubProc(T, Gen, Node);
```

The problem is even worse because it often prevents usage of conditional breakpoints based on Arguments.

```
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Cannot access memory at address 0x8
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6f71700 (LWP 313714)]

Thread 3 "lexe.inc.exe" hit Breakpoint 1, bitGenNode (T=0x0, Gen=0x0, Node=0x0) at ../bitGen/bitGen.c:433
433 fct void bitGenNode(void* T, bitGen* Gen, bitNode* Node) {
(gdb) bt
#0  bitGenNode (T=0x0, Gen=0x0, Node=0x0) at ../bitGen/bitGen.c:433
```

Either GDB should perform the e.g. 7 instructions and then test the conditional breakpoint. Or I need a way to tell GCC to generate a more traditional function start (I'm already using -g -O0).

Comment: Seems you want to skip function prologue. This is what gdb does by default.

Comment: Could you show how do you set Breakpoint 1?

Comment: @ks1322 nothing fancy, something like: `b bitGenNode if Node->NodeCounter==23119`. (Note that it complains about address 0x8 so probably it used Node==0 and tried to offset and deref that.)

Comment: The workaround I have is to open the function's source-code, look up the filename and line-number of the first statement and set my argument-conditional breakpoint on that. But I am not happy with that, particularily because GDB was doing that properly before. (It never showed the bogus Node==0 before the upgrade)

Comment: Can you compile with `-fcf-protection=none` or get GDB 10.1 ? [GDB shows incorrect arguments of functions for stack frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719198/2554472)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `-fcf-protection=none` helped. (At least in this example. I don't have any other reproducable examples lying around) If you add it as an answer, I will accept it. I think my (updated) APT only goes up to GDB 9.2

Comment: Good. Can I mark it as a dup of the other question? The cause is the same - GDB prior to 10.1 doesn't recognize a function preamble that starts with endbr.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  whatever you want